# Why Comparator.comparing() in boolean value return reversed() by default?

Tags: java

I wrote a code using Comparator.comparing() and i provide a method that return a boolean. Sorting should bring on top (first element) all that return true. But the Comparator.comparing() bring on top those that give false. I need to use the reversed() to make it work properly.

I did another test.

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.isRaid() ? 1 : 0));
```

And this bring on top the monsters that are not raid. Why this happen?

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final List<Monster> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            list.add(new Monster("Name" + i, Rnd.nextDouble() < 0.20));
        }

        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Monster::isRaid));

        System.out.println("LEADER -> " + list.get(0).getName() + " " + list.get(0).isRaid());

        for (final Monster monster : list)
        {
            System.out.println(monster.getName() + " " + monster.isRaid());
        }
    }

    static class Monster
    {
        private final String _name;
        private final boolean _isRaid;

        public Monster(final String name, final boolean isRaid)
        {
            _name = name;
            _isRaid = isRaid;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return _name;
        }

        public boolean isRaid()
        {
            return _isRaid;
        }
    }
```

Result of my code:

```
LEADER -> Name0 false
Name0 false
Name1 false
Name2 false
Name3 false
Name4 false
Name5 false
Name6 false
Name7 false
Name8 false
Name9 false
Name10 false
Name11 false
Name13 false
Name12 true
Name14 true
```

While the raid (entry 12 and 14) should be on top.

Comment: What makes you think that the default should be true before false? Generally default sorting orders are ascending, so false (0) then true (1).

Comment: You are not comparing false and true but 1 and 0. 0 comes first and means not isRaid.

Comment: *_isRaid = isRaid;* The only time you should see underscores in Java is in the names of constants (or maybe in digit separation). There's also [no need](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) to invent different names for ctor parameters. `this.isRaid = isRaid` is all that's needed

Comment: And Comparable Boolean orders false before true

Comment: g00se thanks for clarify that, i did not know.

Comment: @JoopEggen they're not comparing 1 and 0, but actual true and false (without converting to int). See [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77157917/why-comparator-comparing-in-boolean-value-return-reversed-by-default/77157949#comment136630961_77157949)

Answer (score 1):

`Comparator.comparing()` performs an ordering by evaluating `false` to `0` and `true` to `1`. So, `false` comes first.

You should specify your custom `Comparator` in order to change the default comparing ordering.

Call [`Comparator::reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()). The `true` values will sort first, before the `false` values.

```
Collections.sort( list,  Comparator.comparing( Monster::isRaid ).reversed() );
```

Comment: thanks @basil-bourque for had improved my answer

Comment: To be nit-picky, it doesn't evaluate false to 0 and true to 1. It simply looks at the boolean values as boolean values, and does not attempt to convert them to int. The JDK implements `Boolean::compare` as `return (x == y) ? 0 : (x ? 1 : -1);` The only ints in this implementation are the return values.